# SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo() for ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type returns null

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to get type info from ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax object but failed.

Here is example that reproduce the problem (see "ti.Type is null" in code):

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace RoslynExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string solutionPath = @"..\..\..\RoslynExample.sln";
            MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                if (project.Name == "RoslynBugProject")
                {
                    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                    {
                        var compilationUnit = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
                        var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
                        new MyWalker(semanticModel).Visit(compilationUnit);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    partial class MyWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
    {
        private SemanticModel _semanticModel;
        public MyWalker(SemanticModel semanticModel)
        {
            _semanticModel = semanticModel;
        }

        public override void VisitObjectCreationExpression(ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax node)
        {
            var ti = _semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node.Type); **<--- ti.Type is null**
            base.VisitObjectCreationExpression(node);
        }
    }
}
```

"RoslynBugProject" project:

```
namespace RoslynBugProject
{
    internal class Query
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var query = new Query();
        }
    }
}
```

How to get type info? Previous version of Roslyn returns not null value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install the Roslyn [Syntax Visualizer](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Syntax%20Visualizer&referringTitle=Documentation), which will show you the syntax tree and also let you explore the SemanticModel APIs as well.

With that installed, you can try right-clicking on nodes and asking for the type symbol:

[image]

In this case, you'll discover a couple things:

- If using "View TypeSymbol (if any)", you can get the symbol from the `ObjectCreationExpression` itself, but not from any of its children (the "IdentifierName" or the "ArgumentList"), so this could be fixed by passing `node` to `GetTypeInfo` instead of `node.Type`.
- If using "View Symbol (if any)", you can get the symbol from the "IdentifierName" but not from the `ObjectCreationExpression`, so you could also fix your code by passing `node.Type` to `GetSymbolInfo` instead of `GetTypeInfo`.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the answer. And thanks for the link to Visualizer. You are very helps me.

Comment: But why Roslyn does not returns type information for TypeSyntax? TypeSyntax is widely used in syntax nodes. And for me it look  a bit strange why I can't get type information from type syntax.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I should have been more thorough. You can use GetSymbolInfo instead of GetTypeInfo when you have a TypeSyntax. Answer updated to explain both options.

Comment: thank you for this, I was going crazy and couldn't find this out myself :)

Comment: Is there a set of grammar production rules for the Roslyn syntax tree? That would save a spectacular amount of grief.