# How to get the type of an argument in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

So I am trying to know the type of some variables in the argument when calling a method. Such as in:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "astring"
        string.Format("zzzz{0}", a);
    }
}
```

So I want to know the type of variable a in string.Format("zzzz{0}, a");
I am trying to change some code so I am using rewriter and here is what I got:

```
public class CustomFormatRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter{

    public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax rootNode){
        if (null != rootNode){
            var arguments =
            from n in secondNode.DescendantNodes()
            where (n.Kind() == SyntaxKind.Argument)
            select n;

            foreach (var argument in arguments)
            {
               var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("arg")
                                                            .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
                                                     .AddSyntaxTrees(rootNode.SyntaxTree);

               var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(rootNode.SyntaxTree);
               var symbolInfo = model.GetSymbolInfo(argument);
               Console.WriteLine(symbolInfo.Symbol);
            }
        }  
        return rootNode;
    }

}
```

But the symbolInfo.Symbol I got is null.

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Don't create a new compilation for each token.

Comment: Instead of visiting invocations and looking for arguments, you should visit argument tokens directly.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for your suggestions! So I need to do something on a specific method call, that's way I am visiting invocation expression so that I can target that method call.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to know the *type* of something, you can call `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo`. This works for all expressions, not just ones that are directly a variable. So not only will passing the expression for `a` give you the type of `a`, but `a.SomeMethod()` will figure out which overload of SomeMethod is being called on `a`, and will give you the type of the return. If your expression is just a number, it'll tell you the type is Int32.

`GetSymbolInfo` only works if the thing you're passing in directly is a reference to a symbol, i.e. it's the name of a local or field or something. In your case, the first argument that's a string isn't going to give you a symbol. It has a type (notably, System.String), but it's not a symbol.

Comment: When I have `var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(argument);`, `typeInfo.Type` still gives null. Any idea why...?

Comment: Call GetDiagnostics() on your compilation. Are there errors that we're not recognizing here?

Comment: I called, and get error "the type or namespace name linq does not exist in the namespace system" and I was able to fix it by`AddReferences(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location);` and some hidden of "unnecessary using directive".

Answer (score 9):

Okay I found out why I am always getting null. Post just in case someone may find it helpful in the future.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535382/semanticmodel-gettypeinfo-for-objectcreationexpressionsyntax-type-returns-null) post very helpful in identifying my problem. So it turns out I am not checking type on the correct "level", as I call it. I used the method in the post(In the syntax visualizer, right click a node -> view typeSymbol) to check for the type of my argument. I found that if I check at "Argument", then there is nothing, which explains why I got null. And if I check the node at the level under the "Argument", it gives you the right type.

So I changed my code to:

```
var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(argument.ChildNodes().First());
Console.WriteLine(typeInfo);
```

And it works.

Comment: This will work (and might be better):

var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(argument.Expression);
Console.WriteLine(typeInfo);

Comment: @Bryan You are a hero!

Comment: I had no idea you could right click that visualizer... LIFE CHANGING

Comment: You can right click the Visualizer???????? AAAAAAAAARG. Why didn't anyone tell me before???

Answer (score -1):

Cast it to [`ILocalSymbol`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ILocalSymbol.cs), then read the `Type` property.

Comment: Do you mean cast `symbolInfo` to `ILocalSymbol`? It cannot be converted...And `symbolInfo.Symbol` is null

Comment: The problem, I think, is he should be calling GetTypeInfo...he's passing non-symbols to GetSymbolInfo.